# Nonstandard Definition of the Radical of A Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, nilpotence

> Find all the radical of the commutative ring $Z_8$.

My book gives the following definition of the radical of a ring: "For a ring $R$, the radical is the set nilpotent elements." Is this standard terminology? However, when I came across [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilradical_of_a_ring), which is defined similarly but goes by a different name. Is my book using standard terminology? If not, what is the standard terminology?

Comment: I just want to make a comment that I don't usually say just the "radical" of a commutative ring $R$ to mean the nilradical.  It can be misinterpreted as the Jacobson radical.

Comment: It's not that it's nonstandard (what standard? no official one, only what we are each used to...) but it is ambiguous. There are lots of radicals of rings. When authors write, they have the freedom to say "I'm only going to talk about the X-radical, so let me just call that the radical." As readers we just have to be sensitive to the context, and hopefully the author is doing his/her best by being clear about it at the outset.

Comment: If you really get into it, there is even more than one *nilradical*. Also, when you decide to mention a book, it's usually best to provide the name of the book and its author, since it might help readers formulate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Atiyah & Macdonald's *[An Introduction to Commutative Algebra](http://wstein.org/edu/2010/581b/books/atiyah-macdonald-introduction_to_commutative_algebra.pdf)* they define the nilradical of a ring to be "the set...of all nilpotent elements in the ring" (chapter 1, page 5). I would say this is the more standard terminology.